# Codeigniter Welcome controller works but other all controller throwing 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed CI application using WAMP sever it works very nice... but now i have deployed this CI application on CPANEL (on my sever)its not working. by default welcome controller is working fine but another all controllers throwing "404 Page Not Found" ..

i made needed changes in view and controller but still 404
Please give me the solution.. Thanks all..

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 
class Login_controller extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->helper('html');
          $this->load->database();
          $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('login_model');
          //load the login model
          
     }
  

     public function index()
     {
    $this->load->view('login_view');
  }
  public function login()
  { 
        
          $username = trim($this->input->post("txt_username"));
          $password = trim($this->input->post("txt_password"));
    $role= trim($this->input->post("urole"));
    
   // $remember =  trim($this->input->post("remember")); 
          //set validations
          //$this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_password", "user_name", "trim|required");
          //$this->form_validation->set_rules("user_passward", "user_passward", "trim|required");
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules("urole", "user_role", "trim|required");

         // if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
//          {
//               //validation fails
//               $this->load->view('login_view');
//          }
//          else
//          {
               //validation succeeds
               if ($this->input->post('btn_login') == "Login")
               {
                    //check if username and password is correct
                    $usr_result = $this->login_model->get_user($username, $password, $role);
               
                    if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                    {
                         //set the session variables
         
                         $sessiondata = array(
                              'username' => $username,
                              'user_role' => $role
                         );
                         $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
       
                         redirect("customer_registration/index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username and password!</div>');
                        redirect('login_controller/index');
                    }
               }
               else
               {
       echo "hi";
                    //redirect('login_controller/index');
               }
          }
     //}
 
}
?>
```

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
| example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There are three reserved routes:
|
| $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
| $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router which controller/method to use if those
| provided in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
| $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
|
| This is not exactly a route, but allows you to automatically route
| controller and method names that contain dashes. '-' isn't a valid
| class or method name character, so it requires translation.
| When you set this option to TRUE, it will replace ALL dashes in the
| controller and method URI segments.
|
| Examples: my-controller/index -> my_controller/index
|  my-controller/my-method -> my_controller/my_method
*/
$route['default_controller'] = 'Login_controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: You just paste your routes.php here, maybe issue is on your controller, also change Login to login, you shouldn't use upper case in there

Comment: Please page controller of the on your having issue with make sure if on Live server if using CI3 All controllers like Welcome.php and not welcome.php

Comment: thanks for reply wolfgang.. i made Login to login still having same issue..i have updated my login controller here..

Comment: Please configure your server to omit index.php and then try, first try in your server adding index.php if it works then configure your server to omit index.php.

Comment: thanks Sudarshan for reply...i did it but not working ..

Comment: Do filenames have the same upper/lower cases as class name?

Comment: thanks ...splash ...yes dear... is a same..but having same prob

Comment: create .htaccess file on root.

Comment: vibhav i have .htaccess file too...can i give you access of server..

Comment: hi all...issue resolved.... problem of windows and Linux hosting...  we have developed app in windows and hosted in Linux ..... only case sensitivity problem..... rocks...